# MYSQL use field with a array of strings with NOT IN operation in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause

MySQL -
Query to find what items were transferred to another organization
Solution below.

table: parent_children

| Tier | Children_Tier |
| --- | --- |
| "NE" | ("NE1","NE2","NE3") |
| "W" | ("W1", "W2", "W3") |

table: Transfers

| From_Tier | To_Tier | Object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "NE" | "NE1" | "shovel" |
| "NE" | "W2" | "hammer" |

## TEST 1

```
Select t.* From Transfers t
JOIN ON parent_children pc ON pc.tier = t.from_tier
WHERE
   t.to_tier NOT IN pc.Children_Tier
```

Expect:

| From_Tier | To_Tier | Object |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "NE" | "W2" | "hammer" |

Actual:

> error near  t.to_tier NOT IN pc.Children_Tier

## TEST 2

```
Select 
  t.*,
  INSTR(t.to_tier, pc.Children_Tier) AS Found 
From Transfers t
JOIN ON parent_children pc ON pc.tier = t.from_tier
```

Actual:

> Found always 0

## TEST 3

```
Select
 t.*,
  INSTR( t.To_Tier , '"NE"|"W2"|"hammer"') AS Found
from Transfers T;
```

Actual:

> Found always 0

## SOLUTION: TEST 2 & 3 had parameters reversed

```
Select
 t.*,
  INSTR( '"NE"|"W2"|"hammer"', t.To_Tier) AS Found
from Transfers T;
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a natural array type. What's exactly the data type of ChildrenTier ?

Comment: I know that doesn't work, looking for a hack around that.  Hate to do it in server code. Was really excited by the INSTR() function thinking that would work, not sure why it doesn't

Comment: Provide both tables as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts.

Comment: *not sure why it doesn't* Because it will find `'NE1'` in `'NE12'`.

Comment: OK, thought so. Made me go back to code with a clear head.  I had the parameters reversed. I updated example 3.

Comment: Made me think that the data type I was using (MEDIUM TEXT) was the issue. But it worked fine when I got the parameters in correct order <HEAD-WALL/>

Answer (score 0):

Question updated with answer.  MySQL does not have array field types to use in where clause but by doing a join on a table using INSTR() allowed to determine if transfer was in or out of the organization.